# usbfs did not claim interface before use

Tags: linux, usb

Using Sunnybeamtool to read out sunnybeam over Rasperry Pi USB port.

I get lot of errors in dmesg which doesn't affect the working (apparently)
program is written in C.

Messages:

```
[30563.867756] usb 1-1.3.3: usbfs: process 32327 (sunnybeamtool) did not claim interface 0 before use
[30563.938025] usb 1-1.3.3: usbfs: process 32327 (sunnybeamtool) did not claim interface 0 before use
```

Hoe do I get rid of these messages?

Comment: Those messages are from *the kernel* regarding sunnybeam.  I do not think you can turn them off.

Comment: Or how do I fix the problem so I don't get those messages?

Comment: You could report it to whoever maintains sunnybeam: http://sourceforge.net/p/sunnybeamtool/bugs/?source=navbar

Comment: Just created a ticket but afraid if michel (creater) is still active?

Comment: Obviously not too active.  5 years is a long time without an update...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the process `sunnybeamtool` has not taken exclusive ownership over the Linux kernel, so `sunnybeamtool` is having difficulty to talk with USB.

The logs you are getting because of

```
[30563.867756] usb 1-1.3.3: usbfs: process 32327 (sunnybeamtool) did not claim interface 0 before use
[30563.938025] usb 1-1.3.3: usbfs: process 32327 (sunnybeamtool) did not claim interface 0 before use
```

Process `sunnybeamtool` might not have proper permissions or maybe the USB open call failed.  You can try to keep a check for USB open call and if fail, try to detach the device.